# Cannot save lightning component Spring '20

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, developer-console, professional-edition, spring-20

In Professional Edition, after the Spring '20 release, I'm not able to save any lightning component. Getting the below attached error. Anyone else facing a similar issue?

Error message:

> nested exception is: common.exception.ApiQueryException: select Id
>   from Site ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:16 sObject type 'Site' is not
>   supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or
>   the describe call for the appropriate names.: Source

[image]

**Update 15/Jan/2020:
Tried the following so far:**

1. Cloned the existing sandbox but still getting same error.
2. Created a new sandbox with Winter '20 able to save lightning component but getting same error while deploying via Change Sets to Spring '20 sandbox.

[image]

Comment: Did Professional Edition allow for Lightning aura components before Spring '20?  I know they don't allow Apex code, but I personally never tried a lightning component...

Comment: Yes, all was working fine few days back, lightning components are allowed in Professional Edition but not apex.

Comment: maybe they realized that they could be interdependent and took it down 

Comment: @Ronnie Professional edition is supported as indicated in the help doc - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: for use - however if you look below where "Available for use" to see `Create Lightning components using the UI in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer Editions, or a sandbox.` for your task (save/create lightning component), it appears that cannot be done in that edition, according to this same doc.@manubkk

Comment: @Ronnie from what I tested before Spring '20 it allowed me to create via UI in a Professional edition sandbox since sandbox can be any edition but I could only create it in Professional edition production by change sets.

Comment: and you cannot do via changesets now? @manubkk Your SS doesn't tell me whether this is a sandbox or not.

Comment: @Ronnie I did not try deploying again because I am not able to make any changes in the sandbox.

Comment: @Ronnie it is CS76 sandbox instance in the screenshot address bar.